# How does Uber app defines the limit to maximum signups for a device?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, uber-api

I got an old phone to operate on. This phone already had an Uber app which the previous user was using. I reinstalled Uber app and register there with my email id and phone number.However, now I am not able to add the paytm wallet in this. While doing so it gives me a message "We are sorry but this device has reached the maximum signup limit." Also, I don't have any paytm app in my phone.

I have few questions like

1) Which party is defining the rules here, Uber or Paytm?

2) Do they maintain their own file(in their apk) for this calculation or it can be some common android file which the app has pickup even after the re-installation and later giving me a message for maximum signups. If this some android file, Can I somehow edit this?

Comment: This does not appear to be a coding question. If it is one, you need to update your question because people will vote to close it for being off topic.

Comment: It depends on the answer to 2) point. If there is no such file in andoird then I think it can be closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The uber app have your Android Device id that's why you can't sign in with another username and password. If you like to change your device ID your phone must be [Rooted](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=what%20is%20android%20root%20access) if your device is rooted then you are able to

### [Change your Device ID](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z88FOqL7gIg)

But changing your device ID it little bit risky if you don't have enough knowledge of android

Comment: so u mean to say device id is a software generated number. its not related to somewhat embedded in its ROM etc. ?

Comment: device id is a id of a android they can maintain maximum login limits for particular app.

Comment: device id will be erased when you wipe out(Factory Reset) your phone.